# Could not connect to VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am using OpenVPN to connect to a VPN, as my work required it, but I am in a country that restrict the VPN usage. Is that any way I can use that VPN ?

I'm getting an error "TLS Error: TLS handshake failed".

Appreciate your help, and thanks for your time,

Comment: This is something you'd have to check your local laws and regulations for. The ISP/government probably has a legal basis for blocking VPNs, and trying to circumvent that could be criminal.

Answer (score 0):

To correct a tls handshake error:

Launch a web browser from a computer or mobile device that is

connected to the router network.

Enter https://www.routerlogin.net.

A login window opens.

Enter the router user name and password.
Note: The user name is admin. The password is the one that you specified when you set up your router. If you didn’t change the password, enter password.

Tap or select ADVANCED > Open VPN.
The Open VPN Service page displays.

Make sure that the Open VPN Service check box is selected.

In the OpenVPN configuration package download section, click the For Smart Phone button and download the router’s VPN configuration files to your iOS device, Android device, or computer.

If you download the configuration files to a computer, unzip the configuration files that you downloaded and send the files to your iOS device or Android device.

The configuration files include the .ovpn file.

Note: For more information, see your user manual.

Launch the OpenVPN Connect app and import the .ovpn file.

In the task bar, select the openvpn client.

Select edit config.

A text editor opens.

Add the line remote-cert-tls server to the file.

Click Save.